Add query parameter from GUI to Power BI direct query
My database contains data for different business-dates and getting all data for all business dates would not be feasible for Power BI. Luckily, I only need the data for a given day.
My idea to solve this would be to modify the query for a Power BI table based on a setting in the GUI, like this:
select * from mydata where business_date = '[value-from-gui-menu]'

Is this possible in some way?

I think you are looking for Dynamic M query parameters in Power BI Desktop
